# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (message.mentions.users.first())

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm coding a functionality on my discord bot in JS about economy,
so I need to get id's of my members and I'm testing it with

```
let defineduser = '';
  if (!args[1]){
    defineduser = message.author.id
  } else {
    let firstMentioned = message.mentions.users.first();
    defineduser = firstMentioned.id;
```

But this doesn't work actually...

I want to make my command '!addmoney' with 2 arguments:
Amount and User.
Actually the amount works and if I'm not giving the second args my code actually works because it's my ID.
I think that `message.mentions.users.first();` is deprecated but it's not mentioned in discord.js docs...

Comment: can you supply live-testable code? use the `<>` button

Comment: Whyy doesn't that work? What have you tried instead?

Comment: lgtm, that should work within the client `message` event passing `'message'` as the parameter.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me... can we see what you are sending?

Comment: I'mnot trying to send a message to the person but just to recover his id from the argument

Comment: Could you tell us what do you see when you `console.log(message.mentions.users.first())` ?

Comment: `console.log(message.mentions.users.first())` returns Undefined when i just say
!add money 100 <user>

Comment: If i'm mentionning someone like me, `!addmoney <amount> @LaskY`
Console returns all my properties, my id , what king of message etc...
But as i make a `!money` (this shows how much i have), the amount was the same as before i've done the command

Comment: When you say `<user>` you mean a user mentioned like `@User`? What's the difference between what you did in the first comment and in the second? (The fact that it doesn't count the money you add may not be related to this, let's first focus on the user detection, then we'll fix that too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.js does have `message.mentions` in their docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions

## Anwser

Lets say the message is `!addmoney 10 <@0000000>` 
**EDIT** When there is a mention `@user` the mention's text is `<@[user's id]>`

And args is `["10", "<@0000000>"]` this is assuming you split the `message.content` correctly.

```
let userID;
if(args[1]){
    let mention = message.mentions.users.first();
    userID = mention!=undefined ? mention.id : args[1];
    //You should also check if the id supplied via args[1] is a valid id.
}
else {
    console.error(`no id supplied`)
    return;
}
```

Note: Most people I've seen just do

```
args = message.content.split(` `);
//args now equals ["!addmoney" "10", "<@0000000>"]
//which means args[1] = "10",
args.shift();
//args now equals ["10", "<@0000000>"]
```

Hopes this helps!

Comment: Yep! This actually works :)
I didn't get how discord deals with these functions